# Which function is correct for cloud masking

Tags: mask, google-earth-engine

I was writing a function to mask cloudy pixels of the Sentinel-2 data.

Function 1:

```js
function cloudMask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10; ###
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11; ###
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
```

Function 2:

```js
function cloudMask(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = Math.pow(2, 10); ###
  var cirrusBitMask = Math.pow(2, 11); ###
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}
```

Which function is correct? 
The difference between two functions is that how `cloudBitMask` and `cirrusBitMask` are defined.

Comment: Did you try them? Are they both working, if so, do the results look different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both functions are correct as they are doing exactly the same thing. Either `1 << 10` or `Math.pow(2, 10)` will result in a number with a value of `1024`.

As we usually use both opaque cloud and cirrus cloud for cloud masking, I suggest keeping the code short and clear as below:

```
function cloudMask(image) {
    var qa = image.select('QA60');
    var allCloudBitMask = (1 << 10) + (1 << 11);
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(allCloudBitMask).eq(0);
    return image.updateMask(mask);
}
```